# How do I find the value of $f(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

Let $f$ be a polynomial such that $f(0)>0$ and $f(f(x))=4x+1$ for all $x\in R$, then $f(0)$ is $?$
So this is what I've tried so far,

$f(f(0))=1$ so $f(f(0))=4f(0)+1$ (*)

Also, $f(f(1))=5$,this implies $f(5)=16f(0)+5$ Now how should I find the value of $f(5)$ in terms of $f(1)$ so that I can solve (*)? Any help is appreciated .

The answer given is $1/2$

Comment: $f$ is a *polynomial*?

Comment: Yes it is  a polynomial

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $f(f(x))$ is a polynomial of degree $n^2$. In your case, $n^2=1$ so $f(x)$ is linear, and you can find it explicitly from the equation $f(f(x))=4x+1$.

Comment: I'm sorry , I didn't understand the part of how I can find it explicitly? Can you please explain? Thank you for answering.

Comment: If $f=a_kx^k + ..... + a_0$ has degree $k$ then $f(f(x) = a_k(a_kx^k + ..... + a_0)^k = a__k^2 x{k^2}$ will have degree $k^2$ so.  $f(f(x)) = 4x + 1$ has degree $1$ so $k^2 =1$ and $k =1$ and $f$ has degree $1$.  So if $f(x) = ax + b$ then $f(f(x)) = a(ax+b) + b = a^2x + (ab+b) = 4x + 1$.  So $a^2 = 4$ and $ab+b=b(a+1)= 1$.  So $a = \pm 2$ and $b=\frac 1{a+1}=-1$ or $\frac 1{3}$.  As $f(0) = b > 0$ we have $a=2, b=\frac 13$ and $f(x) = 2x +\frac 13$.  So $f(0)=\frac 13$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = ax + b$  $(*)$
$f(f(x)) = a^2x + ab + b = 4x + 1$

Comparing coefficients,

$b(a+1) = 1$
$a^2 = 4$

$\implies a = 2, b = \frac{1}{3}$

($a$ is not $-2$ by the fact that $f(0) > 0$, $a = -2$ would result in $b = -\frac{1}{3} \implies f(0) = -\frac{1}{3}$)

Therefore $f(x) = 2x + \frac{1}{3}$ and $f(0) = \frac{1}{3}$

(($*$) comes from the fact that if a polynomial $f(x)$ is degree $n$, then the polynomial $f(f(x))$ is of degree $n^2$)

Comment: How did you get $b(b+1)=4$  and $a^2$=1. The answer given is 1/2. I will write it in the question. Thanks!!

Comment: @NatashaJ Since $f(f(x)) = a(ax + b) + b = a^2 x + ab + b$, you can compare the coefficients of $x$ and the constant term of $4x + 1$ to arrive at $a^2 = 4$ ($a^2$ is the coefficient of x) and $ab + b = 1$ ($ab + b$ is the constant term)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = a_kx^k + a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + ..... + a_0$.

Then $f(f(x) = a_k(a_kx^k + a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + ..... + a_0)^k + a_{k-1}(a_kx^k + a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + ..... + a_0)^{k-1} + ..... + a_0$

If we expand that out we will get a very large polynomial of degree $k^2$.

But $f(f(x)) = 4x + 1$ which is of degree $1$.

So $k^2 = 1$.  And as $k \ge 0$ we have $k = 1$.

So let $f(x) =ax+b$.  And $f(f(x)) = a(ax+b) + b = a^2 +(ab + b) = 4x + 1$.

So we have $a^2 =4$ and $ab+b = b(a+1) = 1$.

So $a = \pm 2$.  $a+1=-1,3$ and $b = \frac 1{a+1}= -1, \frac 13$.

As $f(0) = a\cdot 0 + b = b > 0$ and $-1 < 0; \frac 13 > 0$ we must have $b > 0$ so $b = \frac 13$ and $f(x) = 2x + \frac 13$ and $f(0) = 2\cdot 0 + \frac 13 = \frac 13$.

[Note  $f(f(x)) = 2(2x + \frac 13) + \frac 13 = 4x + \frac 23 + \frac 13 = 4x + 1$.

Comment: Thank you @ fleabood for answering!!